# what is the maximum size for an array in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

It's troubling me building an array of objects with a lot of data in qml using the Windows platform (it's the only one that the crash happens). For some reason the application is crashing if the processing function takes too long!

I'm going to illustrate with a portion of code what i want to do:

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 1400
    Page {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        property int responsiveWidth: 1000
        property int maximumWidth: 900
        ScrollView {
            id:configScroll
            anchors.fill: parent
            GridLayout {
                columns: 2
                width: page.width > page.responsiveWidth ? page.maximumWidth : page.width
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: page.width > page.responsiveWidth ? (page.width - childrenRect.width)/2 : 10
                anchors.rightMargin: page.width > page.responsiveWidth ? 0 : 10
                    Button {
                        property bool test: true
                        text: "array func"
                        onClicked: {
                            var panelModes=[], rows=[],groupsModes=[], panelLabel="panel", sounderLabel="sounder",soundersModeLabel="sounder mode",sounderGroupLabel="sounder group"
                            for(var gSndrModeAdd=0; gSndrModeAdd<1000;gSndrModeAdd++) {
                                panelModes = []
                                for(var pSndrModeAdd=0; pSndrModeAdd<32; pSndrModeAdd++) {
                                    rows = []
                                    rows.push(["C1",1])
                                    rows.push(["C2",1])
                                    for(var sSndrModeAdd=0; sSndrModeAdd<32; sSndrModeAdd++) {
                                        rows.push(["L1S"+(sSndrModeAdd+1),1])
                                        rows.push(["L2S"+(sSndrModeAdd+1),1])
                                        rows.push(["L3S"+(sSndrModeAdd+1),1])
                                        rows.push(["L4S"+(sSndrModeAdd+1),1])
                                    }
                                    panelModes.push({"label":panelLabel, "value": 1, "headers":[sounderLabel,soundersModeLabel],"rows":rows})
                                }
                                groupsModes.push({"label":sounderGroupLabel,"value":1,"nested":panelModes})
                            }
                            console.log("the array is: ")
                            console.log(groupsModes)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This crashes.

If this is not specifically an array problem, is this memory related problem? something like that?

This is necessary to build the structure i want. Is there a way to solve this?

The error i get on console:

`09:45:07: The program has unexpectedly finished.`

`09:45:07: The process was ended forcefully.`

`09:45:07: C:/Dev/QT/build-array-crash-limit-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/array-crash-limit.exe crashed.`

I managed to catch `Memory usage` with `QML Profiler` if i set the first for cycle to 300.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you think that array size causes to the crash? Do you get errors/warnings or whatever? you create for some reason 1024000 objects so perhaps the reason for the crash is memory overflow? What is this code for?

Comment: @folibis i edited to show the error. I will use this code and more to build an object to export information to different file types.

Comment: Not sure that QML/Js is good place for this kind of task. I would do that in C++ but even in this case I would use some strong code optimization. Try to run the code in debugger and see what QML profiler will say about memory usage.

Comment: After running QML profiler and clicking on button it crashes. Nothing shows on it. Or maybe i don't know how to use it.

Comment: Firstly I strongly suggest you to work on your code style. Now it is absolutely unreadable and incomprehensible, no wonder you make a lot of mistakes. Read about [Test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). As for the code - the type of `groupsModes` in undefined but latter you relates to it as an array and call to `groupsModes.push` ... perhaps there are more errors of this kind, I just can't read this code. Besides of that, you are creating millions of JS objects. in pure C++ it could take up to several megabytes, in JS it would be much greater.

Comment: @folibis How would you implement this structure if not in 3 for cycles, at least in a way it doesn't crashes?

Comment: I have no idea what this structure is and what it's for so I can't offer any solution.

Comment: Funny, my qml profiler is showing at least 1 billion bytes allocated and at least 16000 allocations. On the activity monitor, the app rocketed up to 3Gb of memory used. I would say something similar to folibis in that the intensive task should be done in C++. Pass the appropriate parameters to the backend. And *chunk* your array if possible; clearly the high memory usage is an issue.

Comment: @TrebledJ thanks, i think, probably the solution to my problem as pointed by you guys, would be to do this processing on c++ side. I am just trying to do it here in the first place, because i'm using components from qml to do processing too, i haven't put that on this example.

Comment: quick question: are you intentionally re-creating the arrays on each `onClicked` event? it seems like your model contains unique entries, might wanna use a custom `QAbstractListModel` that contains a hashset (`QHash`) that will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the crashing of the application only happens on the windows platform.
In MACOS and LINUX it only blocks for the time of the function processing.

Maybe it really is a memory problem after all, that happens on windows using versions of QT that use MinGW 32-bit.

The solution to solve this problem? 
The usage of **MinGW 64-bit**.

Answer (score 2):

you have a bug here

```
...
for(var pSndrModeAdd=0; 32; pSndrModeAdd++) {
...
```

and the loop will run forever. Change to

```
...
for(var pSndrModeAdd=0; pSndrModeAdd<32; pSndrModeAdd++) {
...
```

Anyway, arrays in QML are just JavaScript arrays, as such have (practically) no maximum size.

Comment: Thanks. That was a bad copy paste. But it crashes if i increase the number of iterations on the for cycle.

Comment: It crashes and doesn't show anything in profiler. Or maybe it's that i don't know how to use it.